# monitoring with AspectJ the non-invocation of a method

Tags: methods, aspectj, invocation

I am trying to use AspectJ for detecting not invoked methods within a method invocation. That is, I would like to know whether a method is not invoked within another method.

In the same line, is it posible to monitor the invocation of a method in a catch or finally block? I would like just to know whether in a JDBC method, the connection’s close method is invoked.

In more detail:

1)  I would like to use it for JDBC methods. In particular, in some cases in JDBC it is necessary to use a transactional context when connecting to the database. In particular, such transactional context is given by invoking the instructions con.setAutoCommit(false);   con.commit(); con.rollback();.
 For example, let’s see an extract of the method for deleting a client from the DB:

```
public boolean deleteClient(String clientId){
Connection con = null;
boolean b=false;
…
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.getProperties("url"));
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
     ….//Instructions for deleting the client 
    `con.commit();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    try {           
               if(con != null) 
                  con.rollback();       
             }catch(SQLException e1) {          
                    e1.printStackTrace();
             }
   }finally { 
        …if (con != null) 
              con.close();          
        …
  }
return b;
```

}`

The point is that, I would like to use AspectJ to advise my students whether their methods like this do not establish a transactional context, that is, whether they do not invoke any of the instructions: con.setAutoCommit(false);   con.commit(); or con.rollback();.

2. Similarly, it is needed to close the connection, normally in the finally block. I would like to advise the students if they forget to invoke the close method.

Any idea for any of the points?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You check whether a method is invoked and negate the result. But this seems kind of trivial, so maybe you should clarify your question.

Comment: Well, it is possible indirectly and I would not call it so trivial because you need **multiple pointcuts/advice** and it involves **manual bookkeeping**, as non-invocation does not trigger any pointcuts, so you need flags. It might get further complicated in multi-threading situations. So I am seconding Nándor's request for sample code (a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just incoherent snippets) and some more context informations about your constraints with regard to multi-threading etc. Then I will be glad to supply you with a comprehensive answer incl. sample code.

Comment: Thank you Nándor and Kriegaex for you suggestions. I have explained my question in more detail.